Зачем нужны токены? qt6 c++
Пишу проект небольшой на qt6 c++, мессенджер. Как я знаю, существует такое понятие как токен, чтобы идентифицировать(?) запросы к серверу. Зачем это нужно если я могу, например, сделать хэш таблицу с ключом в виде указателя на сокет, а в слоте readyread получая отправителя получить информацию для этого сокета? Это какая-то неправильная практика?
QMap<QTcpSocket*, Session*> m_sessions; 
 
void readyRead() { 
    auto session = m_sessions[qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender())]; 
    ...
}


Хранить указатель на сокет можно, но сокет работает только в рамках текущего сеанса связи. Если пользователь обратится к вашему веб-сервису завтра, то нужно создавать новый сокет. Токен же вы можете хранить очень длительное время и сами определяете срок его действия. Так вы можете идентифицировать клиента в любое время.
